# Paper.js: hitTest for obstructed items with mouse event?

Tags: javascript, hittest, paperjs

I have two items one on the other, that is, one blocking the other. Say Item2 is blocked by Item1. Now whenever I use

```
project.hitTest(Item2);
```

It works fine.

But the problem occurs when I use mouse's event.point. When I use

```
project.hitTest(event.point);
```

in

```
function onMouseUp(event){}
```

it only detects the item on top. Is is possible to detect all the items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this will help you: 
http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#contains-point

```
var path = new Path.Star({
center: [50, 50],
points: 12,
radius1: 20,
radius2: 40,
fillColor: 'black'
});

// Whenever the user presses the mouse:
function onMouseDown(event) {
// If the position of the mouse is within the path,
// set its fill color to red, otherwise set it to
// black:
if (path.contains(event.point)) {
    path.fillColor = 'red';
} else {
    path.fillColor = 'black';
}
}
```

It's not the best solution, because you have to loop through all your paths, but I don't know a better solution right now.

Comment: This is really useful when only allowing very special items to be selected. I find this one much better then using hittest.

Answer (score 1):

with newer paper.js version one direct way to get all Items is to use [`hitTestAll()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#hittestall-point):

> Performs a hit-test on the item and its children (if it is a Group or Layer) at the location of the specified point, returning all found hits.

[example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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):

```
var hitOptions = {
    segments: true,
    stroke: true,
    fill: true,
    tolerance: 5,
};


function onMouseUp(event) {
    console.log('******************************************');
    var hitResult = project.hitTestAll(event.point, hitOptions);
    console.log('hitResult (' + hitResult.length + ')' , hitResult);
    if (hitResult) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

alternative you can try to use the normal [`hitTest()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#hittest-point) with an `options.match` filter function.
[example2](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) - only returns a hit result if the bottom-most object is hit:

```
function hitMatchFilter(hitResult) {
    //console.log('hitMatchFilter:', hitResult);
    let flag_obj_is_first = false;
    if (hitResult.item) {
        let hititem = hitResult.item;
        if (hititem.parent.children[0] == hititem) {
            //console.log('hititem isFirst in parent child list');
            flag_obj_is_first = true;
        }
    }
    return flag_obj_is_first;
}

var hitOptions = {
    segments: true,
    stroke: true,
    fill: true,
    tolerance: 5,
    match: hitMatchFilter,
};

function onMouseUp(event) {
    console.log('******************************************');
    var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
    console.log('hitResult', hitResult);
    if (hitResult) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

refer : http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/

hittest must have hitoptions like

var hitOptions = {
    segments: true,
    stroke: true,
    fill: true,
    tolerance: 5
};

var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);